# Different config for Symfony CLI than web requests

Tags: php, symfony, shopware6

We are running Shopware 6, a Symfony 5 application.

For the web requests, we use APCu as cache adapter. It was enabled in the config file `config/packages/framework.yaml` like so

```
framework:
  cache:
    app: cache.adapter.apcu
```

However on the CLI, APCu is not enabled in the PHP config, so we can't use it there, but when we run CLI scripts (using `php bin/console ...`), Symfony uses the same config and tries to use the APCu cache, which results in warnings and in case of `bin/console cache:clear` even in a fatal error.

Is there a way to override the Symfony config specifically for console requests? I read the docs about Symfony Config but that mostly refers to different environment configs using `.env` files, not differing configs dependant on web request or console request.

Comment: Sounds like you are supposed to use a `ChainAdapter`: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34962

Answer (score 1):

You can have different `yaml` config files per environment.

`config/packages/framework.yaml` would contain config settings across all environment.

`config/packages/dev/framework.yaml` would contain config settings only for the `dev` environment. Any settings made here would override settings in `config/packages/framework.yaml`

`config/packages/prod/framework.yaml` would be the same for the `prod` environment. This is where you could set the app cache to apcu.

If you have to specifically run CLI commands in the `prod` environment, this won't resolve the issue but in theory you shouldn't have to regularly manually clear the cache in a `prod` environment. If you must though you could simply `rm -rf var/cache` from the shopware root.

Comment: You can also force the environment by doing `SYMFONY_ENV=DEV symfony console cache:clear` or `symfony console cache:clear --env=DEV`

Comment: I do have to run CLI commands in the prod environment every now and then and the warnings about APCu not being available are not only annoying, but I am also afraid of things not working as expected because of that. I may use the environment configs as a workaround for now, but I am still trying to find a solution to my initial question to change configs based on the source of the request (web or CLI).